# TDD - Am I doing it correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, moq

I have a class that deals with Account stuff. It provides methods to login, reset password and create new accounts so far.

I inject the dependencies through the constructor. I have tests that validates each dependency's reference, if the reference is null it throws an ArgumentNullException.

The Account class exposes each of these dependencies through read only properties, I then have tests that validates if the reference passed on the constructor is the same that the property returns. I do this to make sure the references are being held by the class. (I don't know if this is a good practice too.)

First question: Is this a good practice in TDD? I ask this because this class has 6 dependencies so far, and it gets very repetitive and also the tests get pretty long as I have to mock all the dependencies for each test. What I do is just a copy and paste every time and just change the dependency's reference being tested.

Second question: my account creation method does things like validating the model passed, inserting data in 3 different tables or a forth table if a certain set of values are present and sending an email. What should I test here? I have so far a test that checks if the model validation gets executed, if the Add method of each repository gets called, and in this case, I use the Moq's Callback method of the mocked repository to compare each property being added to the repository against the ones I passed by the model.

Something like:

```
    userRepository
        .Setup(r => r.Add(It.IsAny<User>()))
        .Callback<User>(u =>
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(model.Email, u.Email);
                Assert.IsNotNull(u.PasswordHash);
                //...
            })
        .Verifiable();
```

As I said, these tests are getting longer, I think that it doesn't hurt to test anything I can, but I don't know if it's worth it as it it's taking time to write the tests.

Comment: "Is this good TDD?" is really the wrong question; the more useful question is "Is this working for me and my project?"  Methodologies like TDD are, despite what zealots would have you think, a means to an end, and not an end in themselves.

Comment: -1 This is not a TDD questions, it is a unit testing design question.

Comment: Here is my 2 cents.  I would not expose your dependencies as properties. I have seen this sort of things abused by devs. in the past where they use the dependency the property exposing the dependency within their classes (not pretty at all).  If it's becoming tedious to assemble your SUT class, you can use a factory method to create the SUT class or better still use the test builder pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of testing is to find bugs.

Are you really going to have a bug where the property exists but is not initialized to the value from the constructor?

```
public class NoNotReally {
    private IMyDependency1 _myDependency;
    public IMyDependency1 MyDependency {get {return _myDependency;}}

    public NoNotReally(IMyDependency dependency) {
        _myDependency = null; // instead of dependency. Really?
    }
}
```

Also, since you're using TDD, you should write the tests before you write the code, and the code should exist only to make the tests pass. Instead of your unnecessary tests of the properties, write a test that demonstrates that your injected dependency is being used. In order or such a test to pass, the dependency will need to exist, it will need to be of the correct type, and it will need to be used in the particular scenario.

In my example, the dependency will come to exist because it's needed, not because some artificial unit test required it to be there.

Answer (score 3):

You say writing these tests feels repetitive. I say you feel the major benefit of TDD. Which is in fact not writing software with less bugs and not writing better software, because TDD doesn't guarantee either (at least not inherently). TDD forces you to think about design decisions and make design decisions all. The. Time. (And reduce debugging time.) If you feel pain while doing TDD, it's usually because a design decision is coming back to bite you. Then it's time to switch to your refactoring hat and improve the design.

Now in this particular case it's just the design of your tests, but you have to make design decisions for those as well.

As for testing whether properties are set. If I understand you correctly, you exposed those properties just for the sake of testing? In that case I'd advise against that. Assume you have a class with a constructor parameter and have a test that asserts the construtor should throw on null arguments:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyDependency dependency)
    {
        if (dependency == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dependency");
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void ConstructorShouldThrowOnNullArgument()
{
    Assert.Catch<ArgumentNullException>(() => new MyClass(null));
}
```

(TestFixture class omitted)

Now when you start to write a test for an actual business method of the class under test, the parts will start to fit together.

```
[Test]
public void TestSomeBusinessFunctionality()
{
    MyDependency mockedDependency;

    // setup mock
    // mock calls on mockedDependency

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockedDependency);

    var result = myClass.DoSomethingOrOther();

    // assertions on result
    // if necessary assertion on calls on mockedDependency
}
```

At that point, you will have to assign the injected dependency from the constructor to a field so you can use it in the method later. And if you manage to get the test to pass without using the dependency... well, heck, obviously you didn't need it to begin with. Or, maybe, you'll only start to need it for the next test.

About the other point. When it becomes a hassle to test all the reponsibilities of a method or class, TDD is telling you that the method/class is doing to much and would maybe like to be split up into parts that are easy to test. E.g. one class for verification, one for mapping and one for executing the storage calls.

That can very well lead to over-engineering, though! So watch out for that and you'll develop a feeling for when to resist the urge for more indirection. ;)

To test if properties are mapped properly, I'd suggest to use stubs or self-made fake objects which have simple properties. That way you can simply compare the source and target properties and don't have to make lengthy setups like the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in unit tests (*especially* in TDD), you are not going to test every single statement in the class that you are testing. The main purpose of the TDD unit tests is to test the **business logic** of the class, not the initialization stuff.

In other words, you give scenarios (remember to include edge cases too) as input and check the results, which can either be the final values of the properties and/or the return values of the methods.

The reason you don't want to test every single possible code path in your classes is because should you ever decide to refactor your classes later on, you only need to make minimal changes to your TDD unit tests, as they are supposed to be agnostic to the actual implementation (as much as possible).

Note: There *are* other types of unit tests, such as code coverage tests, that are meant to test every single code path in your classes. However, I personally find these tests impractical, and certainly not encouraged in TDD.